No “System Sounds” appears under Playback in pavucontrol
I use PipeWire under Xubuntu. Unfortunately, I'm not able to set the system sound volume. Normally, the “Playback” panel of Pavucontrol should show “System Sounds”, but there isn't any in my case. How can I make “System Sounds” re-appear in that panel?
